# Zero pad numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, zero-pad, zero-padding

What's the more pythonic way to pad an array with zeros at the end?

```
def pad(A, length):
    ...

A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
pad(A, 8)    # expected : [1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0]
```

---

In my real use case, in fact I want to pad an array to the closest multiple of 1024.  Ex: 1342 => 2048,  3000 => 3072

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For your use case you can use [resize()](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize) method:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
A.resize(8)
```

This resizes `A` *in place*. If there are refs to `A` numpy throws a vale error because the referenced value would be updated too. To allow this add `refcheck=False` option.

The documentation states that missing values will be `0`:

> Enlarging an array: as above, but missing entries are filled with zeros

Answer (score 119):

`numpy.pad` with `constant` mode does what you need, where we can pass a tuple as second argument to tell how many zeros to pad on each size, a `(2, 3)` for instance will pad **2** zeros on the left side and **3** zeros on the right side:

Given `A` as:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

np.pad(A, (2, 3), 'constant')
# array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0])
```

It's also possible to pad a 2D numpy arrays by passing a tuple of tuples as padding width, which takes the format of `((top, bottom), (left, right))`:

```
A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

np.pad(A, ((1,2),(2,1)), 'constant')

#array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],           # 1 zero padded to the top
#       [0, 0, 1, 2, 0],           # 2 zeros padded to the bottom
#       [0, 0, 3, 4, 0],           # 2 zeros padded to the left
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],           # 1 zero padded to the right
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

---

For your case, you specify the left side to be zero and right side pad calculated from a modular division:

```
B = np.pad(A, (0, 1024 - len(A)%1024), 'constant')
B
# array([1, 2, 3, ..., 0, 0, 0])
len(B)
# 1024
```

For a larger `A`:

```
A = np.ones(3000)
B = np.pad(A, (0, 1024 - len(A)%1024), 'constant')
B
# array([ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.])

len(B)
# 3072
```

Comment: Thanks! Does it work if original length is 3000 ? (then padded length should be 3072)

Comment: It should, since the right padding length here is the difference between `1024` and the modular remainder of `len(A)` divided by `1024`. It should be easy to test.

Comment: what if I have a 3d volume to pad?

Comment: This is really the clearest example I'd ever seen. Thank you!!

Comment: this doesn't work for me and I don't understand why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413710/numpy-pad-with-zeros-creates-2d-array-instead-of-desired-1d

Comment: `mode='constant'` is the default value, no need to specify it directly. Docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html

Answer (score 12):

For future reference:

```
def padarray(A, size):
    t = size - len(A)
    return np.pad(A, pad_width=(0, t), mode='constant')

padarray([1,2,3], 8)     # [1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
def pad(A, length):
    arr = np.zeros(length)
    arr[:len(A)] = A
    return arr
```

You *might* be able to get slightly better performance if you initialize an empty array (`np.empty(length)`) and then fill in `A` and the `zeros` separately, but I doubt that the speedups would be worth additional code complexity in most cases.

To get the value to pad up to, I think you'd probably just use something like `divmod`:

```
n, remainder = divmod(len(A), 1024)
n += bool(remainder)
```

Basically, this just figures out how many times 1024 divides the length of your array (and what the remainder of that division is).  If there is no remainder, then you just want `n * 1024` elements.  If there is a remainder, then you want `(n + 1) * 1024`.

all-together:

```
def pad1024(A):
    n, remainder = divmod(len(A), 1024)
    n += bool(remainder)
    arr = np.zeros(n * 1024)
    arr[:len(A)] = A
    return arr
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea for automatic padding to make the length a multiple of 1024 ? I'm writing something but it's highly non pythonic ;)

Comment: @Basj -- Sure, check my update.  I didn't test it or anything, but I think it should work...

Comment: This is what `pad` does but with a lot bells-n-whistles (front, back, different axes, other fill modes).

Answer (score 5):

You could also use [`numpy.pad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

```
>>> A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> npad = 8 - len(A)
>>> np.pad(A, pad_width=npad, mode='constant', constant_values=0)[npad:]
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0])
```

And in a function:

```
def pad(A, npads):
    _npads = npads - len(A)
    return np.pad(A, pad_width=_npads, mode='constant', constant_values=0)[_npads:]
```

Answer (score 5):

There's `np.pad`:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
A = np.pad(A, (0, length), mode='constant')
```

Regarding your use case, the required number of zeros to pad can be calculated as `length = len(A) + 1024 - 1024 % len(A)`.