# Padding a matrix with numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array called `adj=dim(16,16)`. l would like to pad it with zeros to get `new_adj=dim(31,31)`.

I tried...

```
new_adj=np.pad(adj,((15,31),(31,15)),mode='constant')
```

However

```
new_adj.shape=(62, 62)
```

I'm supposed to get...

```
new_adj.shape=(31, 31)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zero pad numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191855/zero-pad-numpy-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html), it explains that each tuple in the second argument specifies how many positions of pad to add at the beginning and end of each dimension. You are adding 15 rows at the top and 31 at the bottom, and 31 columns at the left and 15 at the right, hence the final (62, 62) matrix. If you only want to add rows and columns at the bottom and right, do:

```
new_adj = np.pad(adj, [(0, 15), (0, 15)], mode='constant')
```