# Numpy FFT Zero Padding

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, numpy, signal-processing

Is there a python equivalent to zero padding a function?  For example in MATLAB:

```
x1 = 0.5*np.cos(2*np.pi*f1*t)
x1 = [x1, zeros(1,1000)]
```

Which will pad x1 with 1000 zeros.

Comment: Yes, there is: [`np.pad(x1,(0,1000),mode='constant')`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zero pad numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191855/zero-pad-numpy-array)