# numpy pad with zeros creates 2d array instead of desired 1d

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, padding

I am trying to pad a 1d numpy array with zeros.

Here is my code

```
v = np.random.rand(100, 1)
pad_size = 100
v = np.pad(v, (pad_size, 0), 'constant')
```

> result is 200x101 array, whose last column is [0,0,0,... `<v>`], (leading 100 zeros),
>   and all 1st 100 columns are zeros.

How to get my desired array

> [0,0,0,..0,`<v>`]

of size (len(v)+pad_size, 1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pad` output is 2D because the `pad` *input* was 2D. You made a 2D array with `rand` for some reason:

```
v = np.random.rand(100, 1)
```

If you wanted a 1D array, you should have made a 1D array:

```
v = np.random.rand(100)
```

If you wanted a 1-column 2D array, then you're using `pad` incorrectly. The second argument should be `((100, 0), (0, 0))`: padding 100 elements before in the first axis, 0 elements after in the first axis, 0 elements before in the second axis, 0 elements after in the second axis:

```
v = np.random.rand(100, 1)
pad_size = 100
v = np.pad(v, ((pad_size, 0), (0, 0)), 'constant')
```

For a 1-row 2D array, you would need to adjust both the `rand` call and the `pad` call:

```
v = np.random.rand(1, 100)
pad_size = 100
v = np.pad(v, ((0, 0), (pad_size, 0)), 'constant')
```

Comment: Thanks! Still, how would I get my desired result of shape (200,1)?

Comment: @Gulzar: Do you want a 1D array or not? You don't seem to have a clear understanding of the difference between a 1D array and a 1-row 2D array - you say you want a 1D array, and you try to work with it as if there is no length-1 dimension, but then you say you want a 2D shape. You should figure that out first.

Comment: you are correct. I didn't realize the difference. What I really want is a single row, 2D array.

Comment: actually, `(200, 1)` would be a 1-*column* 2D array. I'll add code for both 1-row and 1-column.

Comment: correct again... sorry about that... I do need a column array. (200,1) is the final desired size

Comment: Answer expanded.

Answer (score 0):

1. ## np.hstack((np.zeros((200, 100)), your v))
2. ## np.concatenate((np.zeros((200, 100)), your v), axis=1)

   may be your desire this:

[image]

Comment: I think you stated different ways to get the result I don't want. How to get the result I DO want?