# How to fill 2d numpy array with some 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array which varies in size from one value to other.

How can I generalize the size by filling in zeros if the input value has less dimension than required?

Exmaple:

Input list with numpy array dimension:
[(40, 173),
(40, 14),
(40, 56),
(40, 173)]

And I want to have all the arrays to be (40, 173), where if it is has lesser size, than filling rest with zeros.

Comment: Start with a `np.zeros((40,173))` array, and copy the input array to the desired slice.

Comment: How to how to copy it to desired size? I want (40, 173), but some input data is of smaller size.

Comment: `res[a:b, c:d] = input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called zero-padding. Assuming you want to pad an array `A`:

`np.pad(A, ((0, rows), (0, cols)), "constant")`

You can set:

- `rows = 40 - A.shape[0]`
- `cols = 173 - A.shape[1]`

More info: [Zero pad numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191855/zero-pad-numpy-array/38192105)

Comment: Still returns same size array. Don't know if I am missing something

Comment: It's working now. I figured out that output of np.pad had to be saved

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to a `zeros` array:

```
In [160]: res = np.zeros((40,173),int)                                                               
In [161]: res[0:20, 0:30] = np.ones((20,30),int)
```