# Zero pad an array to the next power-of-2 size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

As mentioned in [Zero pad numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191855/zero-pad-numpy-array), this function zero pads an array:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
B = np.pad(A, (0, 3), 'constant')   # array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0])
```

**Question: Is there a helper function in `numpy` or `scipy` that automatically zero pads an array to the next power-of-2 size? (Useful for FFT purposes, etc.)**

Of course I can do something like

```
def padpower2(A):
    return np.pad(A, (0, int(2**np.ceil(np.log2(len(A)))) - len(A)), 'constant')
```

but it's alway tricky to remember/rewrite, so having a ready-to-use `numpy` function would be better.

Comment: It's too specialized to be part of `numpy`.  If it is particular useful for FFT, there might be something in the `scipy.signal` module, or where ever FFT is implement.  But most likely you'll have to write your own utility.

Comment: I'm not aware of any numpy built-in that can do this. Regarding the computation of the next power of 2, `1 << (x - 1).bit_length()` is a more efficient approach.

Comment: Good to know @GZ0. Feel free to post an answer with this helpful trick!